# Are opinions considered sentences in Logic?

Tags: logic, philosophy

I am beginning to read the book titled forallx An Introduction to Formal Logic by P.D. Magnus. This is an open source book. On page 4 Magnus states:

[image]

In this open source book found here: https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Fullerton_College/Math_100%3A_Liberal_Arts_Math_(Claassen_and_Ikeda)/05%3A_Logic/5.01%3A_Logic_Statements  the author states that opinions don’t count as sentences because one person might consider it true while another might consider it false.
[image]
This author wouldn’t consider “Rhubarb is tasty.” as a sentence. So which definition is correct to use? Thank you!

Comment: You should cite one of the books that you think conflicts with what Magnus writes, otherwise we can't come to a fair judgment. The key point is that logic is about reasoning from a well-defined set of agreed principles.

Comment: Sounds good. I’ll edit the question.

Comment: Math is not a study of opinions. Any mathematical terminology should be precisely defined before it is used.

Comment: @Karl There are plenty of mathematical or meta-mathematical statements which are opinions, at least so far as humans know.  In fact, opinions are *necessary* for mathematical research.  "The Goldbach Conjecture is False" would be one, longstanding, example of an opinion which is not known as true, nor false.

Comment: I don't see why both can't work out as correct.  Those authors both define their terms.  One allows for a 'sentence' to be an opinion.  One defines a 'statement' as necessarily true or false and thus not an opinion.  In effect, the later definition implies that at present The Collatz Conjecture and The Goldbach Conjecture are not 'statements'.  This strikes my ears as strange, but so long as one defines one's terms, I don't see any confusion or issue.  But, I would keep in mind that sentences about unknown matters are necessary for research.  Thus, opinions are necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I much prefer Magnus’ treatment over the second one. Logic doesn’t care about whether some statement is actually true or not, let alone whether we know or believe it to be true. Logic only cares about implication: it asks: *If* we consider such-and-such to be true, what else would be true.

In fact, in logic we can work with completely non-sensical statements like ‘Hupflubbers are brig’ and ‘Nothing that is brig is shomsooza’, because logic will now tell you that it logically follows from those statements that ‘No hupflubbers are shomsooza’.

Now, what *is* a potential worry is cases of ambiguity and vagueness, especially as we try to apply logic to real life. For example, if I use ‘bank’ to refer to a financial institution in one sentence, then we should not combine that with some other sentence where I use ‘bank’ to refer to a river’s edge. And in real life, we may declare that ‘John is a tall person’ and that ‘Susan likes tall people’, but we should not be so quick to infer that Susan likes John: the context under which John is considered ‘tall’ may be quite different from the contect under which Susan likes ‘tall’ people and besides, does Susan literally like *all* tall people?!

But like I said, these considerations are mainly for when you try to apply logic to real life. As an abstract and idealized branch of mathematics, all that matters for logic is that the expressions have the abstract **form** of a statement … which is exactly what allows us to do **formal** logic.

And while the second source does allude to the potential issues of vagueness and ambiguity, I really don’t like how it makes it sound as if it is about the difference between facts and *opinions*. Yes, as explained above, vagueness and ambiguity can hinder the application of logic to real life. But, as long as we are clear on our terms, then why does it matter whether something is fact or opinion? If the house is beautiful, and if I like beautiful things, then as long as the two sentences agree on their use of ‘beautiful’, we can infer that I like the house. That is, we can do logic on statements that are opinions just as much as on statements that are facts.

In fact, the line between ‘fact’ and ‘opinion’ is a lot more blurry than we like to think anyway. Is it a fact that Pluto is not a planet? Or even that $1$ is not a prime? Remember Pluto used to be a planet, and $1$ used to be a prime. And it wasn’t as if we suddenly realized that we were wrong about these beliefs. We didn’t say: ‘Oh shoot! And here I thought $1$ was a prime, but it turns out I was wrong about it! Dang!’ No, it simply was that we felt it was more useful and practical to regard Pluto as something other than a full-fledged planet. So the point is that one can have interminable discussions about what is ‘fact’ and what is ‘opinion’ or what would even make something ‘true’, but fortunately, as explained earlier, in the abstract context of mathematical formal logic we can completely sidestep such discussions: it just doesn’t matter!

Indeed, as should be clear from what I have been saying, the goal of logic is *not* to ‘establish truth’. As such, I find the second source confusing, if not inaccurate.

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation cleared this up for me. The only thing that I’m trying to understand is the meaning of “logic is that the expressions have the abstract form of a statement” in your explanation. What is meant by form? I have heard this mentioned a few times.

Comment: @Dr.J Take the example I gave in my post about hupflubbers. That inference is of the form ‘All A’s are B’s. No B’s are C’s. Therefore, no A’s are C’s’.  This is a logically valid inference, no matter what the A’s, B’s, and C’s stand for. So this is what formal logic does: it looks at the abstract form of the statements (often further symbolized by symbols like $\to$ and $\forall$), and it can tell on the basis of that abstract symbolic form or pattern whether the inference is valid or not, even if you don’t know what the statements are about. Like I said, truth does not matter!

Answer (score 1):

This question would likely better be served in the philosophy stack exchange, as  after reading a few sentences it appears that Magnus's book is more focused on philosophy than mathematical logic. With that being said, I think Magnus means opinions in the sense that they can be well defined. For example, if "A piece of food is tasty because it has certain proteins in it" and "Rhubarb is a piece of food with special proteins in it", then "Rhubarb is tasty" would make sense as a sentence in logic. On the other hand, This second author is talking about opinions in general, if my two sentences are "You should eat tasty food" and "Rhubarb is tasty", Rhubarb is tasty has no real truth value, because its up to the eater. In *philosophy* (to my knowledge), many arguments are formed around opinions because they deal with real life issues that cannot be proven true or false, and are a matter of judgement. Either way, don't take anything I say as concrete, seeing as how this is a philosophy question less of a math one.